# Преобразование массива

Tags: php

Всем, привет! Помогите, пожалуйста преобразовать один массив в другой.

Массив который надо преобразовать:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  Петя : 'Поет' 
    [1] =>  Вася : 'Играет' 
    [2] =>  Коля : 'Танцует' 
    [3] =>  Дима : 'Курит' 
)
```

Массив в который надо преобразовать (при преобразовании убрать одинарные кавычки)

```
Array
(
    [Петя] => Поет 
    [Вася] => Играет 
    [Коля] => Танцует 
    [Дима] => Курит 
)
```

Думал может таким способом сделать, но как дальше сообразить не могу:

```
$firstElement = explode(":",$array[0]);
```

А как добавить к ключу какое-нибудь слово, например слово "_SCHOOL", чтобы было вот так:

```
Array
(
    [Петя_SCHOOL] => Поет 
    [Вася_SCHOOL] => Играет 
    [Коля_SCHOOL] => Танцует 
    [Дима_SCHOOL] => Курит 
)
```

к значению у меня получилось присоединить, а к ключу как?

Comment: ДРУЗЬЯ, ВСЕМ СПАСИБО ЗА УЧАСТИЕ!!! ВЫ МНЕ ОЧЕНЬ ПОМОГЛИ!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$arr1=...;//1ый массив
$arr2=array(); //пустой 2ой массив
foreach($arr1 as $key=>$value){
    $temp = explode(":",$value);
    $arr2[$temp[0]]=str_replace("'","",$temp[1]);
}
```

Есть более красивые способы.

Comment: СПАСИБО! Все прекрасно работает.
А как добавить к ключу какое-нибудь слово, например слово "_SCHOOL", чтобы было вот так:

    Array
    (
        [Петя_SCHOOL] => Поет 
        [Вася_SCHOOL] => Играет 
        [Коля_SCHOOL] => Танцует 
        [Дима_SCHOOL] => Курит 
    )

к значению у меня получилось присоединить, а к ключу как?

Comment: `$postfix = "_SCHOOL";
...
for..
$arr2[$temp[0]+$postfix]=str_replace("'","",$temp[1]);
`

Comment: Ой, а почему пробел добавляет между [Петя]  и [_SCHOOL]:

    [ Петя _SCHOOL] => Поет

Comment: Потому что я забыл про trim();
`$arr2[trim($temp[0]).$postfix]=str_replace("'","",$temp[1]);`

Comment: Уууу круто :) СПАСИБО!

Answer (score 4):

```
function transform(array $array) {
    $result = array();

    foreach ($array as $value) {
        $items = explode(':', $value);
        $result[trim($items[0])] = trim($items[1], ' \'');
    }

    return $result;
}

print_r(transform(array(
    "Петя : 'Поет'",
    "Вася : 'Играет'",
    "Коля : 'Танцует'",
    "Дима : 'Курит'",
)));
```

=>

```
Array
(
    [Петя] => Поет
    [Вася] => Играет
    [Коля] => Танцует
    [Дима] => Курит
)
```

Comment: Благодарю! Работает :)

А как добавить к ключу какое-нибудь слово, например слово "_SCHOOL", чтобы было вот так:

    Array
    (
        [Петя_SCHOOL] => Поет 
        [Вася_SCHOOL] => Играет 
        [Коля_SCHOOL] => Танцует 
        [Дима_SCHOOL] => Курит 
    )

к значению у меня получилось присоединить, а к ключу как?

Comment: как-то так:

    function transform(array $array, $key_suffix = '_SCHOOL') {
        $result = array();

        foreach ($array as $value) {
            $items = explode(':', $value);
            $result[trim($items[0]).$key_suffix] = trim($items[1], ' \'');
        }

        return $result;
    }

Comment: Все разобрались :) СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ ЗА УЧАСТИЕ!